# Send multiple dynamic arguments to jquery event functions

Tags: php, jquery

I want to send multiple arguments to JQUERY event functions.For sending one data i put it in value attr in html code.

```
<li id="<?php echo 'v'.$value['vehicleid'] ?>" value="<?php echo $value['vehicleid']; ?>" >
```

And get data in JQuery event function with `$(this).val()` But i don't know how can i pass multiple php data to JQuery event function!
these data are dynamic and produced by php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use val() on an `li` it is supposed to be used on form elements like input for which there is a valid attribute called `value`

For an li you can use data attributes

```
<li id="<?php echo 'v'.$value['vehicleid'] ?>" data-vehicleid="<?php echo $value['vehicleid']; ?>" >
```

and use:

```
var vehicleId = $(this).data('vehicleid');
```

For passing multiple data you can seperate each id with some char like "-":

```
<li id="<?php echo 'v'.$value['vehicleid'] ?>" data-vehicleids="<?php echo $value['vehicleid1']. '-' .$value['vehicleid2']; ?>" >
```

which should produce something like:

```
<li id="1234" data-vehicleids="1234-3456-5678" >
```

then do

```
var vehicleIdsArray = $(this).data('vehicleids').split('-');
```

just make sure charachter used for seperation is not used for vehicle ids

This should help you:

```
<ul id="list">
<li data-vehicleid="1234" data-vehiclename="renault" data-vehicle-color="silver">Renault</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul#list li').click(function(e){
    var vehicleId = $(this).attr('vehicleid');
    var vehicleName = $(this).attr('vehiclename');
    var vehicleColor = $(this).attr('vehiclecolor');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Quote from Resig:

> I think what is most enticing about this whole specification is that
>   you don't have to wait for any browser to implement anything in order
>   to begin using it. By starting to use data- prefixes on your HTML
>   metadata today you'll be safe in knowing that it'll continue to work
>   well into the future. The time at which the HTML 5 validator is
>   integrated into the full W3C validator your site will already be
>   compliant (assuming, of course, you're already valid HTML 5 and using
>   the HTML 5 Doctype).

Comment: Thanks.I have multiple data can i use data for each of them? like this data-id="<?php echo $id ?>" data-name="<?php echo $name?>" and etc.Ang get them values in jquery with data(dataattrname)?If i have a php array and i don't know which data in that array how can send this array data to JQUERY event function?

Comment: @user1344766 I have updated the answer, the 'event' is not clear, I assume its a click on li.

Comment: thanks.This trick only work on html5 enabled browsers or can work on browsers that doesn't support html5?

Comment: jQuery is cross browser. For specific information regarding compatibility chack post by Resig promting to use data-attributes right away, the link is on answer by #trujillo

Answer (score 1):

I came across something similar the other day.

Try using the html5 custom data attribute.

John Resig (the king of jquery and general javascript ninja) first posted about it [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes).

so:

```
<li id="vehicle<?php echo 'v'.$value['vehicleid'] ?>" data-vehicle="<?php echo    $value['vehicleid']; ?>" >
```

Then access it using the jquery .data function. see http://api.jquery.com/data/.

If you have a lot of data you want to add I recommend using an object literal

```
{ vehicleId:    <?php echo 'v'.$value['vehicleid'] ?>,
vehicleName: <?php echo 'v'.$value['vehicleName'] ?>}
```

as in the example on the jquery website.

Comment: Just to comment on sabithpocker answer - it would be better and more explicit to avoid 1234-3456 type data (where you need to use split("-")) and use an object literal to pull the data out that you need.

Comment: Thanks.But if users browsers doesn't support html5 how can use this trick?

Answer (score 0):

I am not one hundred percent sure which kind of event are you pertaining to. But you can pass multiple arguments inside the function(..HERE..). It should be separated by commas. Its like this.

```
    $('selector').change(function(arg1,arg2,arg3){
          alert(arg1+arg2+arg3);
   });
```

In this example i am using change event for the selector 'selector'.

Comment: i want to send data when .hover event on li.But i don't know how can i send multiple data to .hover event! How can i embed data in li and get them in JQuery function?Or how can i send multiple data to JQUERY event function.These data are dynamic and produced by php

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a function to handle the event

```
    function handleEvent(data-vehicleid,data-vehiclename,data-vehiclename)
    {
        alert(data-vehicleid + data-vehiclename + data-vehiclename);
    }
```

Then on your li,

```
<li onmouseover="handleEvent(<?php echo $variable1;?>,<?php echo $variable2;?>,<?php echo $variable3;?>)">Renault</li>
```